# Database system or .CSV file for Ticketting app?

Tags: database, csv

I am trying to build a ticket dispensing application for different events or clients. Besides knowing the principles of how a DBMS and .csv files work, which I'd studied on my own, I don't know how these tools are actually deployed in the real world to create such an application. Suppose I want to generate several batches of tickets(with probably different formats) for different events: eg 2000 tickets, 3000 tickets, 5000, etc. My questions are:

Do I create a .csv file for each batch of tickets, then store them in a tickets-column of a database table?

or

should I create a tickets table(or tables, depending on the formats), then proceed to store each field of the ticket(eg: ticket-no, gate-no, seat-no, etc) into the corresponding table-column?

I believe both systems would work, but I'm more concerned about what is the best-practice in terms of effectiveness and efficiency in the real world. These are just ideas that come to me, but I'd appreciate any pointers to what i might be missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First I would recommend writing to interfaces in your code.  That way you can have a CSV implementation, a database implementation, whatever you want.  Your code just always reads/writes using an interface.

Secondly I would recommend storing *everything* in a database and nothing in a CSV file.  If you need CSV files later, you can simply export them from the database.  You can do that straight from a table or using a query.

Comment: Thanks @ryan. Suppose I might need to generate tickets of different formats, do I create different db-tables according to the ticket-format, or just the one table, meaning that some fields would not be used because the format at the time does not require them?

Comment: I would say it's not a black and white issue. Depends on much the tickets vary. If 90% of the fields are the same, then I would probably make one table and accept a few fields that might be NULLs. If they share 50% of the same fields, I would make different tables.  If you think their formats will diverge over time, I would make different tables.